# Image Location for Xcode Projekt

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, interface-builder

I was making my first projekt and suddenly figured out that all images are not located in the projekt, only references. Is it true? How can I put them directly in the projekt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete all images from your project and add them again. This time the window with the option to copy them into your project should appear again!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you drag & drop or add an image into your "projekt" there's an option to copy the file into your folder, mark it.

Comment: I know, but this window doesn't appear any more, when I am adding an image. Also, I'd like to change locations of images, that are already in the projekt.

Comment: the window doesnt appear if the file is already in the project.

Comment: sure. how can I change location of the image,that is already in the projekt(there is only a reference)?